# How can I quickly compare a list and a set?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, set, low-latency

Say I have a list

```
l = [1, 1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

and two **disjoint** sets of equal length

`a = (1, 3)` and `b = (2, 5)`

and I want to get the elements in `l` that is in `a` and `b` separately like

`[1, 1, 1, 3]` and `[2, 5, 5]`

I tried list comprehension like `[x for x in l if x in a]` but that takes a long time if the length of `l`, `a`, and `b` is 10^5

EDIT: the sets are disjoint sets of equal length.

EDIT: What I need to do is count the elements in `l` that is common in `a` (with duplicates) minus that with elements of `l` in `b` (with duplicates too). So the above example should output `1`. The problem is if the list and sets are as long as 10E5. Using filter and itertools still takes too long.

EDIT: I got it now! Apparently I have to wrap the input sets with `set()`! I didn't at first (I only got it via `input().split()`) because the inputs are unique already but didn't know list and sets are very different and sets are faster! Well, TIL for me.

Comment: Can you use different data structures to avoid needing this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you aren't using appropriate data structures for the job.
Using tuples to represent sets might be *ok* for *small* sets in this case, 
but for *large* sets, you can expect to search an average
of half the combined size of the sets for each element in the list
that is actually in one of the sets.
For each element in the list that is *not* in either set,
we must search *all* elements of *both* sets to determine that.

So any algorithm based on these data structures
(i.e., representing sets using tuples)
will at best be `O(m*n)`, where `m` is the size of the list
and `n` is the size of the sets.

There really isn't any way we can reduce the `m` component
— we have to examine each element of the list to determine which set
(if any) it belongs to.

We can, however, reduce the `n` component.
How?  By using a more efficient data structure for our sets.

Fortunately, this is not hard, as Python includes a built-in `set` type.
So the first step is to construct the two sets:

```
a = set((1, 3))
b = set((2, 5))
```

Now, we can easily (and efficiently) determine if an element `e` is in one of the sets:

```
e = 1
e in a # => True
e in b # => False
```

Now, we just need to loop over the input list and accumulate the result:

```
l = [1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 1]
result = 0 # accumulator for result
for e in l:
  if e in a:
    result += 1
  elif e in b:
    result -= 1

print result # prints "2"
```

Comment: I wasn't using tuples, the use of parenthesis is only to show that it's a set. But I was using list that's why I'm having the problem. I wrapped them with `set()` to make them sets (I didn't at first because the inputs are already unique) and it worked. Apparently I really need to use the appropriate data structure for the job (because sets are faster)

Comment: @johnjullies **could you, please, confirm the quantitative evidence** of the speed of **`set`**-based solution with 1E+5 set-elements compared against the **`numpy/numba`**-based one? The timing construct with about a 25 ns resolution was posted below as: `aStopWATCH.start();<_aFuncUnderTEST_>;aStopWATCH.stop()`. Thanks for your re-consideration, `johnjullies`

Comment: @user3666197 Assuming I'm correct about `numpy.in1d` being `O(m*n)` (or `O(n^2)` for two equal-sized arrays), the constant time-factor of `set` solution (for list and set sizes of 10^5) would need to be something like 100,000 (10^5) times greater that the constant time-factor of the `in1d` solution before the `in1d` solution would be faster.  That just doesn't seem plausible.  But feel free to do the timing analysis if you want.

Comment: @NathanDavis thanks for your note, Nathan. You might have already noticed, @johnjulles has changed a bit the post and **Task Definition** shifted. Your **`set`**-based proposal stopped it's meeting the defined goal, as @johnjulles posted expected / requested MCVE result to be **`== 1`**, while your algorithm yields `==2`. Nevertheless, your remarks on O()-metrics are fair as an assumption, my experience with python memory-management and memory-access penalties make me doubt about real code execution & will try the benchmarks for 1E+5 as that was my primary interest to know. Will post updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain` and `repeat` functions from `itertools` module :

```
>>> from itertools import repeat,chain
>>> a={1,3}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((repeat(i,l.count(i)) for i in a)))
[1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Note : As a more efficient way you can use a `set` container for `a` which has O(1) complexity for membership checking, and you don't need call the `list` if you don't need the result as a list, `chain.from_iterable` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Or as a pretty much optimized approach you can use `numpy` which is specially strong when you are dealing with huge lists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([1, 1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])
>>> a = (1, 3)
>>> l[np.in1d(l,a)]
array([1, 1, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Quickly?

As Kasramvd proposed a smart **`np.in1d()`** approach and Wesley´s horse-power **`pandas`** framework was also proposed, **let me set the quantitative yardstick** to be able to work with individual solutions qualities.

### Let´s be both fair and quantitative:

the more, once 10E+5 items are in the game. **Efficiency & speed** of processing, **memory** handling, **vectorisation** potential and (perhaps) hidden **adverse side-effects**, CPU-cache latency masking poorer or better the off-CPU data access times ( and many more trolls ) - **these are all enemies, we have to live with in production:**

---

### SUMMARY:

Nathan's `set`-based method was way faster for all the scales that were tested.

Nathan's method handled both small, `1E+4` and `1E+6` scaled sets considerably faster, taking the fruit from advantageous searching capability hidden inside python hashable collections of unique elements in **`set`**-s ( as `set` type was exactly introduced for ).

However, the **`O( m*n )`** / **`O( n^2 )`** could not be proved.

These assumed complexity-models ought mean, that with growing `m`,`n`-scales, the adverse performance penalties on `numpy`-based method as compared to the `set`-based method on the same `list`/`set`-dataSets shall grow and accelerate for larger `m`,`n`-s.

Growing `set`-scales demonstrated the inital edge becoming even smaller on larger scales.

**1:3** speed advantage on **`1E+4`** scale degraded to still respectfull, but smaller advantage of some
**1:2** speed advantage on **`1E+6`** scale.

**The real code-execution has made the a-priori assumption of the task O(m*n)/O(n^2)-complexity not to be confirmed in-vivo.**

---

### How to test it?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch
>>> aStopWATCH = Stopwatch()
>>> l = [1, 1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> a = (1, 3)
>>> b = (3, 5)
>>> npL = np.array( l )
>>> npL
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])

>>> npA = np.array( a )
>>> npA
array([1, 3])

>>> import numba # ______________________________was not me who has said QUICKLY
>>> @numba.jit   #                                                       QUICKLY
... def getLinA( aListAsNumpyARRAY, aSetAsNumpyARRAY ):             # << Kasramvd
...    return    aListAsNumpyARRAY[ np.in1d( aListAsNumpyARRAY,
                                              aSetAsNumpyARRAY
                                              )
                                    ]
>>>
>>> aStopWATCH.start();getLinA( npL, npA );aStopWATCH.stop()
array([1, 1, 1, 3])
113513L                 # runs a JIT-compiler on a first call ... pay 113,51 [ms]

>>> aStopWATCH.start();getLinA( npL, npA );aStopWATCH.stop()
array([1, 1, 1, 3])
653L                    # runs a pre-compiled code on 2nd+ ...... wow   0,65 [ms]

855L                    # runs a pre-compiled code on 2nd+ ...... wow   0,86 [ms]
857L                    # runs a pre-compiled code on 2nd+ ...... wow   0,86 [ms]
698L                    # runs a pre-compiled code on 2nd+ ...... wow   0,7  [ms]
690L                    # runs a pre-compiled code on 2nd+ ...... wow   0,7  [ms]
```

### Hint:

Yes, there is no dinner for free.
As you see, once we have to pay a cost for JIT-compilation.
However, thanks to the Travis OLIPHANT's great **`numba`** tool, no one can stop us from a "pre-mini-call" ( to get the JIT-compiler do it's duty )

```
getLinA( npL[:2], npA[:2] )
```

and next re-run the full scale with already compiled

```
getLinA( npL[:1E+9], npA[:1E+9] )
```

---

### Ex post discussion inspired by idea exchange with `Nathan Davis`

```
>>> def NathanListPROCESSOR( aList = [1,1,3,2,5,7,8,3,2,1],
                             setA  = set( ( 1, 3 ) ),
                             setB  = set( ( 2, 3 ) )
                             ):
...     accumulator = 0
...     for item in aList:
...         if item in setA:
...            accumulator += 1
...         elif item in setB:
...            accumulator -= 1
...     print accumulator
...     return
...
>>> NathanListPROCESSOR()   #_______________________EXPECTED:    == 2
3                           #_______________________O/P DEFINED: == 1
```

*Timing: kindly ref. to variance in timing-results as practical code-execution artifacts appear ( variance in cache dirtiness, )*

```
>>> aStopWATCH.start();NathanListPROCESSOR();aStopWATCH.stop()
3
  1207L
   491L
   279L
   350L
  1478L
  1172L
  1698L
  1488L
  1449L
  9688L
  1466L
```

For objects scaled to **`1E+4`** and **`1E+6`** sizes:

```
>>> aStopWATCH.start();NathanListPROCESSOR( aLIST, setA, setB );aStopWATCH.stop()
-1
  2582L
  2673L
  2529L
  2524L
  2888L
  2693L

>>> aStopWATCH.start();getLISTinSET( npLIST, npSetA, npSetB );aStopWATCH.stop()
0
129983L
 12068L
 10699L
 10930L
 10857L
 10999L
 10954L
 10994L
```

With some help of `numba`:

```
>>> @numba.jit
... def numba_getLISTinSET( npList, npSetA, npSetB ):
...     return ( len(       npList[ np.in1d( npList, npSetA ) ] ) -
                 len(       npList[ np.in1d( npList, npSetB ) ] )
                 )
>>> aStopWATCH.start();numba_getLISTinSET( npLIST, npSetA, npSetB );aStopWATCH.stop()
0
165320L
  7047L
  7328L
  7378L
  7898L
  7519L
  7556L
  7277L
  7296L
  7292L
  7303L
  7302L
  7426L
  7369L
  7307L
```

Finally the *almost*-**`1E+6`** scales:

```
>>> setA = generateSet( 1000000 )
>>> len( setA )                                      # the cost of uniqueness
235836
>>> setB = generateSet( 1000000 )

>>> npSetA = np.array( list( setA ), dtype = np.int )
>>> npSetB = np.array( list( setB ), dtype = np.int )

>>> aLIST = list( ( np.random.random( 1000000 * 1.1 + 10 ) * 1000000 * 10000 ).astype( np.int ) )[:1000000]

>>> len( aLIST )
1000000
>>> npLIST = np.array( aLIST, dtype = np.int )

#----------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------------
#---------------------|                                           |-------------
>>> aStopWATCH.start();numba_getLISTinSET( npLIST, npSetA, npSetB );aStopWATCH.stop()
6
406061L
403946L
409831L
409329L
408920L

#----------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------------
#---------------------|                                       |-------------
>>> aStopWATCH.start();NathanListPROCESSOR( aLIST, setA, setB );aStopWATCH.stop()
785334
200755L
196791L
195540L
196606L
202483L
197094L
199481L
196651L
200969L
198856L
202039L
200152L
202364L
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `numpy.in1d` in `O(m*n)`, where `m` and `n` are the size of the respective arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
a = (1, 3)
b = (3, 5)
l2 = list(filter(a.__contains__, l)) # [1, 1, 1, 3]
l3 = list(filter(b.__contains__, l)) # [3, 5, 5]
```

Comment: It still takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see how this plays with your dataset.

```
from pandas import Series
l = Series([1, 1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])
a = Series((1, 3))
b = Series((3, 5))
a_answer, b_answer = list(l[l.isin(a)]), list(l[l.isin(b)])
```

Reason:  Pandas has calls implemented at a lower level than Python so depending on the data type of the numbers it could be better for you than a pure python solution.